# How to run a bash script in python and use the variables that where defined in that script

Tags: python, bash, variables

I'm running a bash script inside of a Python script, and I need to use the variables that were defined inside of the bash script, in the Python script.

For some context, here is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
updates=$(/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check 2>&1)
all=${updates%";"*}
security=${updates#*";"}
```

Here is how I am calling it in the Python script:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/checkupdates"])
```

I want to use the variables that were defined in that bash script ('all' and 'security') in this SQL update statement (which is part of the Python script):

```
cursor.execute("update dbo.updates_preprod set updates_available = ?, securityupdates_available = ? where hostname = ?",(all, security , socket.gethostname()))
cnxn.commit()
```

Is it possible to do this? If not, could I run 2 separate scripts (each script would echo one of the variables) and grab the stdout of each script and define it as a variable in Python?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: bash has to display values (using `echo`) and then Python can get this text with values and use it in SQL query. But I would display `updates` to get and change it  in Python. I would even run `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check 2>&1` directly with `subprocess`.

Comment: instead of `call()` you should use `output = subprocess.check_output(...)` or `output = subprocess.run(...).stdout`. More in documentation: [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Mixing languages is never a good design choice, probably better to rewrite the bash script in python.  i.e. why not call `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check` from `python`?

Comment: @cdarke Of course... (bad habits)

Answer (score 1):

In the end it was much easier to call that command directly from the Python script.

`output = subprocess.check_output("usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check", shell=True)
all,sec = output.decode().split(';')`

Thanks to @cdarke and @furas for the suggestion.

Comment: @furas also suggested that